# modify data frame based on regex using gsub in r

Tags: r, string, character, gsub

I have been matching text strings between two vectors in a dataframe.  Several values have exactly three characters and match up as part of another word in some other string.  I would like to find the regular expression for this.  Here is an example:

```
a <- c("urban", "crabtree", "rba", "rba hks","barbara", "lederbach")
b <- c("rba", "rba", "rba", "rba", "rba", "rba")

df <- data.frame(a, b)
```

I would like to substitute a blank space (i.e. "") for those values where "rba" only appears as part of the word.  The desired output is:

```
b <- c("", "", "rba", "rba", "", "")
```

So it's sort of like:

```
grep("\\b...\\b", df$a, value = TRUE)
```

But I want to modify column b and insert "" wherever there is no match.

I'm aware that %in% can be used for exact matches, but I was hoping for something using gsub:

```
funb <- function(x) gsub("\\b...\\b", "", x)
df$b <- lapply(df$b, funb)
```

but I haven't had much luck.  Clearly somthing is amiss, can someone help me get the desired result?  Any advice or suggestions would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the `b` column for? Wouldn't something like `a[!grepl("\\brba\\b", a)] <- ""` work?

Comment: @DavidArenburg the b column is the column of matches.  so from a larger data frame, "rba" is the string that matched best with those in column a.  So I want to keep column b, but I want to make it look like the "final" vector above.

Comment: Would that work `library(stringi) ; a[!stri_detect_regex(a, paste0("\\b", b, "\\b"))] <- ""` ?

Comment: Try [`sub("(?s)^(?!.*(?:\\brba|rba\\b)).*","", x, perl=TRUE)`](http://ideone.com/yDhChT)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, but it didn't work.  I was trying to use something more general, because not all of my examples look like the one above, hence i tried with the "\\B...\\B" escape in the gsub function.

Comment: Did you try what I've suggested?

Comment: @DavidArenburg it works for this example, but it changes column a rather than b.  I was hoping for something with gsub because i want to repeat it for lots of cases that are similar to but not exactly the same as the one above.

Comment: This is a very general solution. I have no idea what you talking about. I guess we can't help you without a reproducible example. Your example see, not to have any relation to your real case

Comment: @DavidArenburg I didn't say it didn't work, I really appreciate the suggestion.  I just need to modify it to do exactly what I want it to do.

Comment: Like I said, it is very general. It uses both columns, it allows flexible regex. I can't guess anymore beyond that. Maybe someone else can

Comment: @DavidArenburg you're absolutely right.  It works great, I just am unsure about how to read the paste command.

Comment: `paste0()` is literally `paste(..., sep = "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @David Arenburg's comment above, the general solution to this problem is:

```
b[!stri_detect_regex(a, paste0("\\b", b, "\\b"))] <- ""
```

which edits elements in column b, as desired.